# Reset Finder Sidebar

Tags: macos, finder, catalina, mojave, preferences

Is there anyway to reset the Finder sidebar?

I thought deleting the finder and sidebar preferences and then restarting would have done this, but it does not.

Comment: What's wrong with it? Why do you feel the need to blanket reset as opposed to just reverting whatever changes you made?

Comment: It has multiple items in the favourites that a user does not want (~100). It would be good to have a way to easily reset it to default.

Comment: I found this, written by our own moderator, grg - https://georgegarside.com/blog/macos/finder-sidebar-preferences-location/ [though it's above my paygrade ;)